# Find the value of this sum

Tags: calculus

Find the value of this sum:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3^n(n+1)}{n!}$$

I know that I should use power series, but how?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{3^n(n+1)}{n!} = 3 \cdot \frac{3^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} + \frac{3^n}{n!}$$
for all $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^n(n+1)}{n!}&=3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^n}{n!}\\
&=3\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^n}{n!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^n}{n!}\\
&=3e^3+e^3\\
&=4e^3
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:  Let

$$f(x)=xe^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{x^{n+1}\over n!}$$

How can you get the $n+1$ out of the exponent?

Answer (score 0):

the sum written out is $$y = 1 + \frac 2{1!}x+ \frac{3}{2!}x^2 + \frac{4}{3!}x^3+\cdots  \tag 1$$ with $x$ replaced by $3.$
we can integrate $(1)$ from $0$ to $x$ to get, 
$$\begin{align}\int_0^x y\, dx &=  x + \frac 1{1!}x^2+ \frac{1}{2!}x^3 + \frac{1}{3!}x^4+\cdots \\
&=x\left(1 + \frac 1{1!}x+ \frac{1}{2!}x^2 + \frac{1}{3!}x^3+\cdots\right) \\
&=xe^x\tag 2\end{align}$$ 
differentiating $(2),$  we have $$y = xe^x + e^x.$$  therefore $$y(3) = 3e^3 + e^3=4e^3. $$